# Obtener el ultimo valor deseleccionado de un multi select con JQuery

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Tengo el siguiente multiselect:

```
<div class="input-field">
     <select name="id_empresa[]" id="select_empresas" multiple required>
          <?php
             $ids = array_column($id_empresa, 'id_empresa');                                    
             foreach ($empresas as $empresa) { 
                 echo '<option value="'.$empresa->id_empresa.'" '.(in_array($empresa->id_empresa, $ids) ? 'selected': '').'>'.$empresa->nombre .'</option>';                                   
                 //echo '<option value="'.$empresa->id_empresa.'" '.((in_array($empresa->id_empresa,$id_empresa->id_empresa))? 'selected': '').'>'.$empresa->nombre.'</option>';
                 //echo '<option value="'.$empresa->id_empresa.'">'.$empresa->nombre.'</option>';
             }
          ?>
     </select>
     <label>Empresas</label>
</div>
```

Y quiero obtener el `value` del último `option` que fue deseleccionado. Este es mi codigo JQuery:

```
$('#select_empresas').on('change',function(e) {
      alert( $(this).val());
});
```

Sin embargo, me muestra todos los resultados, separados por comas, pero solo al seleccionar y si deselecciono el último `option`, me devuelve null.

¿Alguien ve qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: No queda del todo claro lo que pretendes

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con este código:

```
var ultimo = ''; // Valor deseleccionado
var ahora = ''; // Valor seleccionado
$('#select_empresas').change(function(e) {
  ultimo = ahora;
  ahora = $(this).val();
  alert(ultimo);
});
```

Lo que hacemos es establecer una variable `ultimo` para el valor recientemente deseleccionado, y otra variable `ahora` para el valor seleccionado actualmente. La función `.change()` se llama cuando ocurre un cambio en la opción seleccionada del select (valga la redundancia). Aprovechamos este evento para hacer esto: El valor de `ultimo` lo hacemos igual al valor de `actual`, y el valor `actual` lo dejamos igual al valor que acabamos de seleccionar.

Quizás al principio no haga mucho sentido, ahora bien, la segunda vez que lo hagamos, el valor que tenemos en `ahora` lo movemos a `ultimo`, y dejamos en `ahora` el valor actual. Así en `ultimo`, siempre tendremos el valor anterior.

Answer (score 1):

Si además de obtener todos los `options` seleccionados, deseas obtener el valor del último seleccionado y deseleccionado, podrías asociarle un onclick a los `option` y que se vaya sobreescribiendo el valor del que se ha hecho click, para así tener siempre el del último que fue seleccionado o deseleccionado:

```
    var ultimo_seleccionado = '';
    var ultimo_deseleccionado = '';

    $('#select_empresas option').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':selected'))  {
        ultimo_seleccionado = $(this).val();
    }
    else {
        ultimo_deseleccionado = $(this).val();
    }
});

alert(ultimo_seleccionado);
alert(ultimo_deseleccionado);
```

Comment: Creo que el if está justo al revés (debería ser: if (!$(this).is(':selected'))  {), además de que los alert no van a funcionar ahí, tendrían que estar dentro de la función change

Comment: Los alerts los puse fuera para indicar que en cualquier momento puede recuperar cual fue el último option que se seleccionó o deseleccionó. En cuanto a la condición, tienes razón, los tenía cambiados. Ahora ya debería cumplirse bien la condición.

Answer (score 0):

He corregido tu script y en vez de apuntar al select apuntamos a los options con el evento click, y he puesto ese condicional para que solo el ultimo desmarcado sea pintado.

```
$('#select_empresas option').on('click',function(e) {
    if($(this).is(':not(:checked)')) {
        alert($(this).val())
    }
});
```